# Set Up VPN on home network and use on home PC

Tags: vpn, home-networking, openvpn

I was thinking of setting up my own VPN on a Raspberry Pi and linking it up to my router at home and then using the VPN on my PC which is on the same network.

I've only ever used VPNs before, not gone in depth into how they work. Can I set up my VPN on my network and use a PC on the same network and connect to the VPN?

I will be using OpenVPN and wanting to hide my internet use e.g. downloads, history etc.

Edit:
I could set up the VPN at work. Would that then work/ hide all my internet traffic? Will the internet history be hidden, will work's ISP or my ISP see the history. (BTW I just like the idea of privacy, I have nothing to hide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a typical ISP at home, you likely have one (public, and traceable) IP address.  That means whatever you access from your home could potentially be tracked back to your IP (to you, in other words).  However you access the internet from within the confines of your home network, be it your smartphone, laptop, raspberry pi, or even a local server, it will all use the same interface into your home, e.g. your cable or DSL modem, which has that public IP.

If you set the VPN server up at work, you might gain a little more privacy, but work's ISP will likely then be able to track your browsing.  Your home ISP will not, if your VPN connection is configured correctly (encrypted, using the VPN server's DNS, etc).

What you probably really want to try is a [VPN service](http://lifehacker.com/5935863/five-best-vpn-service-providers).

Also, do not confuse internet activity with browsing history -- your browser will store your visited URLs, cache, cookies, and other data, unless you use the private browsing mode provided by your browser.

Comment: In other words, is there any sense to hide from the world inside your own home when everyone knows who lives there?

Comment: As opposed to this answer - if you want to keep your browsing habits private I would suggest using onion services like TOR - great for browsing but avoid streaming videos through it.